# How to connect to the Azure Compute Emulator remotely to test a web role from an iPhone

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I need to test and debug my web app from an iPhone, but the Azure Compute Emulator appears to only listen on 127.0.0.1 and so it is not accessible from external machines.

Anyone know how to change that?

If it is impossible to change, does anyone have a suggestion for how to set up port forwarding to work around this limitation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This limitation is by design for security reasons. There are, as you noe, a bunch of scenarios where it would be useful to bypass this restriction such as running a test/int server or accessing from mobile devices.

It is easy enough to circumvent though. You simply need to run a reverse proxy server.

My favourite approach here is to use FIddler as this has the added benefit of being able to watch the traffic.

Take a look at this article and it should provide you with sufficeint guidance. If not coment back and I'll write up a blog post with my step-by-step guide.

http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/reverseproxy.asp

Comment: I did not end up using Fiddler and instead used a dedicated port forwarding app, but the Fiddler instructions work just as well.