# DynDNS - accessing my Window Azure dev storage

Tags: azure, dyndns

I'm trying to solve the following task.
On my home machine I've got local development Windows Azure storage - it's mapped to my local ip 192.168.YYY.XXX, ports - 10000 - 10002. In my routing settings I've got the corresponding mapping for these ports - HTTP, ports 10000-10002 -> 192.168.YYY.XXX, ports 10000-10002.
When I'm trying to acess my blobs in the storage like this - http://192.168.YYY.XXX:10000/devstoreaccount1/storagename/megapic_url.jpg - it wokrs fine. BUT when I'm trying to do it like this - htt://myhomeurlABC.dyndns.org:10000/devstoreaccount1/storagename/megapic_url.jpg - it (Browser) says it cannot access it. I've checked also my Firewall settings - ports 10000-10002 is opened in both In-bound (and Out-bound) rules. I've also checked my port 10000 with http://www.canyouseeme.org/ - it says that ports are opened.
Does anyone know how to make it? Any help will be appreciated!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is because the storage emulator only listens to the local IP address.  There are a couple ways to work around this:

- http://fabriccontroller.net/blog/posts/remotely-accessing-the-windows-azure-compute-emulator/
- [How to connect to the Azure Compute Emulator remotely to test a web role from an iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8625075/how-to-connect-to-the-azure-compute-emulator-remotely-to-test-a-web-role-from-an).